# How do I compose Nanoparsec parsers?

Tags: haskell

I'm working through Steven Diehl's [Write You a Haskell](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/002_parsers.html#nanoparsec), and I just started the Nanoparsec portion. I understand how parsers can be used to parse any given input, but how do I compose them to parse composite input?

The specific puzzle I'm trying to solve is how to compose a string parser from a list of character parsers. The example in the article is this:

```
satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy p = item `bind` \c ->
  if p c
  then unit c
  else (Parser (\cs -> []))

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char c = satisfy (c ==)

string :: String -> Parser String
string [] = return []
string (c:cs) = do { char c; string cs; return (c:cs)}
```

How does this line return a string?

```
string (c:cs) = do { char c; string cs; return (c:cs)}
```

It looks like it creates a number of character parsers, but I don't understand how they get applied to a string passed in. If we expand the recursive calls, it looks something like this:

```
string (c:cs) = do { char c; string cs; return (c:cs)}
string (c:cs) = do { char c; 
                 do { char c; 
                  do { char c; string cs; return (c:cs)}
                 return (c:cs)}
               return (c:cs)}
```

etc, etc. How does this actually work?

Comment: A `String` is a list of `Char`s, so `type String = [Char]`. So it first parses a `char` (if possible), and then a `string` with the rest of the list, of that all matches, then we succeed.

Answer (score 3):

A `char` "consumes" the character if it matches. So if we use `char 'a'`, and the next character to parse is indeed an `'a'`, we "move the cursor" one position further, and return `'a'`.

`string` aims to do the same, but for a list of `Char`s, so a `[Char]`, or equivalent, a `String`. It does that by looking at the `String`. If the `String` is empty, then nothing has to be done, we can simply return an empty list (`String`) as well.

In case the string contains at least one element, then we call `char c` on the *first* character of that string, and then we recurse on the tail of the string, eventually we return `(c:cs)` (the string that we already passed as a parameter to the `string` function). We do not take the result of the parser itself into account, we simply return the string that was given, *if* the parser indeed matches the string.

This is thus done by working with a sequence of `char` calls that each check if the character is indeed the one we need, and if so we keep moving the cursor, and checking the next character.

If we thus perform a `string "foo"`, this is equivalent to:

```
string "foo" = char 'f' >> char 'o' >> char 'o' >> return "foo"
```

If however in the middle the character does not match, the parser will not move the cursor back. Therefore the following parsing will fail:

```
Prelude Parsec Control.Applicative> Parsec.parse (Parsec.string "faa" <|> Parsec.string "foo") "" "foo"
Left (line 1, column 1):
unexpected "o"
expecting "faa"
```

Since the `"faa"` is tried first, and this will already match the first character `'f'`, so that means that the cursor has moved passed `'f'`.